# C++ Builder application crash in VCL before WinMain is called

Tags: c++builder, vcl, access-violation, rad-studio

I am lost in a debugging session, because I am not able to locate the root of an access violation exception on application startup.

Is there any documentation on the VCL startup process/runtime?

The stacktrace looks like this:

```
Vcl::Forms::TApplication
\
 initialization
  \
   __init_exit_proc
   \
    __wstartup
```

What happens when the application gets started? It all happens before `WinMain` gets called, and before `InitControls` get called in `Vcl.Controls`. This strange behavior didn't happen in an earlier RAD Studio version. What is calling the function in `Vcl::Forms`?

I have already read that the linker should have similar problems for a long time, and that disabling "Incremental Linking" should help, but unfortunately it didn't.

I don't understand technically the effects of the project on the exception, if the application hasn't even started yet. Might something have gotten overwritten in the linking stage, because of the large project size?

Is there anything I could try? How can I debug where everything starts?

If I catch the exception, the application startup process continues, and `InitControls` gets called. But in the older RAD Studio version, the order was different, first `InitControls` and only afterwards `Vcl::Forms::TApplication`, so that `Self` was not null.

EDIT:
The talk about the `static initialization fiasco` made me remember the beginning of the problem and that the order is already guaranteed by the statement `pragma package(smart_init)` ([#pragma package](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/de/Pragma_package)):
The exception did only begin to occur after I had commented the pragma statement in the main unit, because of the original error I was getting in `Vcl.Graphics`, like:
`EInvaliGraphicOperation - Class instance of` CLSID_WICImagingFactory `get created (800401F0)`

Error occured in:

```
Vcl.Graphics
\
 constructor Vcl::Graphics::TWICImage.Create
 \
  Vcl::ImageCollection::TImageCollectionSourceItem::Create -> Self:????
  \
   Vcl::ImageCollection::TImageCollection::Add
   \
    InitButtonsImageCollection()
    \
     Vcl::DbCtrls::TDBNavigator::Create::()
     \
      __init_exec_proc
      \
       __wstartup
```

And, as already mentioned, this only started to happen in Sydney. This is somewhere deep down the riverside in the VCL, I guess.

Comment: _" This strange behavior didn't happen in an earlier RAD Studio version."_ - Which version was that and which version are you using now? Does it happen for even the shortest VCL program you create? Do you have any global objects in your application? Do you know what [static initialization order fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof) is?

Comment: Did you enable the VCL's Debug DCUs in your project options so that you can step through the VCL's source code with the debugger at runtime?

Comment: Thanks for your replies and link. With Rio it still worked, now with Sydney the problems have arised. I am able to debug the pas files, but without any gain: I am inside Vcl.Forms with `Self` being NULL, because it got called too early. It was called from `initialization` which brings me right into the CPU window, with the call to `Vcl::Forms::TApplication::GetTitle()`. This is right after startup code, no unit has been initialized yet, this is before `Application.Run`, etc. I would like to understand the theory, which makes no sense at all to me. Other projects in Sydney do work.

Comment: Ok, but you didn't answer my question: _"Do you have any global objects in your application? "_

Comment: Yes, sorry, there are a couple of static globals in the code.

Comment: @kvirk You need to tag me (@-sign + my name without spaces) or else it's just pure luck if I'll see your answer.  Ok, globals. Have you made sure that static initialization fiasco is not happening?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Thanks for the hint with the tag. I have edited my original post above, you made me remember the root of the issue.